# How to revoke root permission to an app in adb?

Tags: applications, adb, root-access

I think I have got a scam app in my device. I granted it root access and then whenever I open an app it,the scame app closes the app. Please help me I am stuck in here.
Aah my head is aching.

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/192154). The correct question would be how to solve this problem. Then the answer would be: `adb uninstall <package_name_of_scam_app>`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, does the ADB shell have root access? If so, all you need to do is access the ADB shell via a computer (I assume, that you know how to do that already, since you asked that you'd like to solve it specifically through ADB) and type in the following command: `pm revoke *scamming apps package name here* android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER` This will revoke the root permission of the app. You might wanna revoke more of it's permission if you want to easily uninstall it, though.

Answer (score -1):

Open Settings. Then Apps. hit the top 3 dots on top screen to show system apps.
then scroll all the way to the bottom of the apps list ,you may or may not see a app you do not know or a weird app with no name, if so delete this app right away it is a virus.
Usually you have to do this is the app in question is not coming up in the normal app list.